# Perl dbi prepare is putting wrong quote

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

My code is similar to the below:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ? (`id` bigint(100) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT");
$sth->execute('test');
```

I end up with the error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''test'
```

From the trace I found perl DBI put single quote around the table name, which mysql doesnt like. How to tell DBI not to put any quote or to put (`) instead of single quote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just doing what you asked. When given a string, `?` is equivalent to a string literal. So

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE field = ?
```

means

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE field = 'test'
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM ?
```

means

```
SELECT * FROM 'test'
```

You need to use

```
$dbh->prepare("
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ".( $dbh->quote_identifier('test') )." (
             `id` bigint(100) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
          )
");
```

Comment: @user3360140 Right. See [Placeholders and Bind Values](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Placeholders-and-Bind-Values) in the DBI documentation, which says: _With most drivers, placeholders can't be used for any element of a statement that would prevent the database server from validating the statement and creating a query execution plan for it._

Comment: Or look at the MySQL documentation, which does not permit arbitrary expressions where the table name is expected in a CREATE TABLE statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use a placeholder for a table or column name.
PreparedStatement will interpret this value as a string and make sinlge quotes around it.

Comment: In my code I make new tables with same schema. Thats why I was trying achieve some efficiency with the create table query. Any other way I can do it ?

Comment: @user3360140 only with string concatination