# How to prepare a pragma statement in Sqlite using Perl?

Tags: perl, sqlite, prepared-statement, dbi

I tried to prepare a pragma statement:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare (q{pragma table_info(?)})
```

but I get the following error:

```
DBD::SQLite::db prepare failed: near "?"
```

What is wrong with the prepare string?

Comment: That is how you prepare a pragma statement. The problem is that you used `?` where an arbitrary expression is not permitted.

Comment: Duplicate of [Perl dbi prepare is putting wrong quote](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32177733/589924)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may prepare PRAGMA statements just as you are doing, but your statement has a syntax error.

When given a string, `?` is equivalent to a string literal. So

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE field = ?
```

means

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE field = 'test'
```

and

```
PRAGMA table_info(?)
```

means

```
PRAGMA table_info('test')
```

The problem is that you're suppose to give

```
PRAGMA table_info(test)
```

As such, you need to use

```
$dbh->prepare("PRAGMA table_info(".$dbh->quote_identifier('test').")")
```

Comment: Is it a general limitation of `prepare`, that it can be used only for values and not for identifiers? Or is `prepare` in my example not aware of the context?

Comment: If placeholders were to be allowed to represent identifiers as well as values, then `SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE x = ?` would be illegal as both identifiers and values are allowed where the `?` is located.

Answer (score 5):

From the [DBI docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Placeholders-and-Bind-Values):

> With most drivers, placeholders can't be used for any element of a
>   statement that would prevent the database server from validating the
>   statement and creating a query execution plan for it.

So, I can only assume that the placeholder in this situation is preventing the database server (or self-contained database engine in this case) from validating the statement.

Even if the statement *could* be prepared, according to the [SQLite `PRAGMA` docs](https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info), it looks like `table_info` is expecting an unquoted table name parameter. DBD::SQLite wants to [quote all bind values by default](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::SQLite#Functions-And-Bind-Parameters), so that would cause a separate issue anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You asked "Is it a general limitation of prepare, that it can be used only for values and not for identifiers? Or is prepare in my example not aware of the context?"

You can only bind (prepare) values, not table names or column names. This is true for all relatonial databases afaik.

Using preparing (binding) of parameters makes it possible for sqlite to reuse execution plans, so it makes sqlite much faster.